# Ajax 500 Failed to load resource error

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

Everytime I load Datatables I get this error. Anyone has any idea why?

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

The link:
http://cts360.ctscloudapp.com/simple.html

simple.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
    <title>Editor example - Basic initialisation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.14/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dataTables/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dataTables/examples/resources/syntax/shCore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dataTables/examples/resources/demo.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.14/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/dataTables/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/dataTables/examples/resources/syntax/shCore.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/dataTables/examples/resources/demo.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/dataTables/examples/resources/editor-demo.js">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "/queries/vendor.php",
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "Company:",
                name: "company"
            }, {
                label: "Brief Description:",
                name: "briefDescription"
            }, {
                label: "Contact:",
                name: "contact"
            }, {
                label: "Contact Title:",
                name: "contactTitle"
            }, {
                label: "Work:",
                name: "work"
            }, {
                label: "Mobile:",
                name: "mobile"
            }, {
                label: "Email:",
                name: "email"
            }
        ]
    } );

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        ajax: "/queries/vendor.php",
        columns: [
            { data: "company" },
            { data: "briefDescription" },
            { data: "contact" },
            { data: "contactTitle" },
            { data: "work" },
            { data: "mobile" },
            { data: "email" }
        ],
        select: true,
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );



    </script>
</head>
<body class="dt-example">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Brief Description</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Contact Title</th>
                        <th>Work</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

vendor.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Example PHP implementation used for the index.html example
 */

// DataTables PHP library
include( "../dataTables/php/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'vendors' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'company' ),
        Field::inst( 'briefDescription' ),
        Field::inst( 'contact' ),
        Field::inst( 'contactTitle' ),
        Field::inst( 'work' ),
        Field::inst( 'mobile' ),
        Field::inst( 'email' )
        )
    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check the error log on the server for the details.

Comment: error_log shows only php errors.. are there another error_log for ajax

Comment: You're calling PHP with AJAX, those are the correct errors.

Comment: Try an absolute path to vendor.php

Comment: 500 means there was an error on the server when trying to process the ajax call, so you need to debug the php. it might help you in general to learn the meaning of the various http status codes. you can easily google and find a list

Comment: There was extra ")" that's why error appeared. I removed ) before ->process( $_POST ) and issue solved.